# python Concurrent.futures: as_completed to map

Tags: python, concurrency, concurrent.futures

I've parallelized some code, but need preserve the order jobs are submitted with the order they are received

I've been smashing my head against this for some time and getting nowhere

```
import concurrent.futures
par_result = []
with concurrent.futures.ProcessPoolExecutor(big_number) as executor:
        future_thing = [executor.submit(fnc, param1, param2,\
                                                      counter) for counter in range(another_number)]
        for future in concurrent.futures.as_completed(future_thing):
            par_result.append(future.result())
```

How is this rewritten into a format like

```
with concurrent.futures.ProcessPoolExecutor(big_number) as executor:
        par_results = executor.map(fnc, (param1, param2, counter))
```

such that it executes counter times